# Solution of second order differential equation involving an exponential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am a undergraduate student. I have tried my best but I could not solve the following equation:

$$y''+(x+1)y'-2y=(1-x^2)e^x;$$

$$0 \le x \le 1;$$

$$y(0)=-1;$$

$$y(1)=0$$

Comment: What exactly is the demanded solution, some qualitative properties, a numerical solution, an exact symbolic solution? What have you tried, what can you use?

Comment: The solution containes the Hermit function